# How do I remove the "Shutdown" menu entry from Gnome's system menu?

Tags: gnome, shutdown, redhat-enterprise-linux

We have a lab with multiple RedHat EL5 machines running the Gnome desktop environment.  When developers are done using the machine sometimes they miss the logout button and click the Shutdown button by mistake (easy to do, I've done it myself).  Needless to say, for those remoted into the lab it's sometimes devastating.  Is there a way to remove the Shutdown entry for all users from the Gnome menu?

*Note:  I do not mean Shutdown on the greeter, but the Shutdown button on the menu drop down that is next to logout, sleep, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in RHEL 6, and this was my solution: http://www.shaunrowland.com/fsync/2011/04/20/removing-shut-down-from-the-gnome-panel-in-rhel-6/

The lockdown editor does not solve the problem, unless you want to remove "Log Out" as well. This is what I did in fact, but I added "Log Out" back myself with a new menu item. I don't know if this will work with RHEL 5, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

does the [lockdown](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown.html.en) editor do what you need.

Comment: This looks like it's more for kiosk type installations.  While it would remove the shutdown functionality, it wouldn't allow user's to login & logout.  That's a must have in a lab environment.